# is it possbile to run local server on mobile device using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, client-server, offlineapps

I want to create client/server offline application. Server should be hosted on a mobile device. Other devices throught a browser should get some content from serrver. Is it possible at all? Is it possible using phonegap? Could anyone give me advice about it?

Answer (score 0):

I use this chrome plugin in a couple of enterprise apps:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket

It works on Android and iOS, is very stable, and you can use it as socket server/client and also as webserver.

**Update:**

First: If you are developing Cordova-Apps, then make a decision what you want to use (Cordova, Phonegap, Ionic, …). Don't mix things and read the documentations.

Second: If you want to install a Cordova plugin from npm, the syntax is:

```
cordova plugin add [npm-name]
```

For installing the chrome-sockets-plugin, use:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket
```

Before you start writing a server-client-socket app with this plugin, read the full documentation from Google. It is not a task which works out of the box and needs some lines of code and some experience in Javascript.

Comment: I'm new with phonegap, so, please, sorry for my stupid questions.
How to apply this plugin to my application?
I'm trying to add this plugin by the command: 
$ phonegap plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket.git 
After than I have a "window.chrome" equal to "undefined".
What I have to do, to make this thing work?

Comment: Thanks, for support and advice.